# Using sed to replace text with curly braces

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I am trying to find the following text

```
get_pins {
```

and replace it with

```
get_pins -hierarchical {proc_top_*/
```

I've tried using `sed` but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I know that you need **#** in front of curly braces but I still can't get the command to work properly.

The closest I've come is to this:

```
sed 's/get_pins #{#/get_pins -hierarchical #{#proc_top_*\//g' filename.txt > output
```

but it doesn't do the replacement I wanted above.

Comment: Why do you need to enclose `{` with `#`?  That is not correct.

Comment: @starbox, See updated answer. I just tested with `csh` and reproduced your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@merlin2011's answer shows you how to do it with alternative delimiters, but as for why your command didn't work:

It's actually perfectly fine, if you just remove all `#` chars. from your statement:

```
sed 's/get_pins {/get_pins -hierarchical {proc_top_*\//'g filename.txt > output
```

There are *two distinct escaping requirements* involved here:

- Escaping literal use of the regex *delimiter*: this is what you did correctly, by escaping the `/` as `\/`.
- Escaping characters with special meaning *inside a regex in general*: **this escaping is *always* done with `\`-prefixing**, but in your case there is NO need for such escaping: since you're NOT using `-E` or `-r` to indicate use of *extended* regexes - and are therefore using a *basic* regex -  `{` is actually NOT a special character, so you need NOT escape it. If, by contrast, you had used `-E` (`-r`), then you should have escaped `{` as `\{`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the curly braces, it's in the `/`.

This is exactly why `sed` lets you do alternate delimiters.

The line below uses `!` as a delimiter instead, and works correctly for a simple file with `get_pins {` in it.

```
sed 's!get_pins {!get_pins -hierarchical {proc_top_*/!g' Input.txt
```

Output:

```
get_pins -hierarchical {proc_top_*/
```

**Update**: Based mklement0's comment, and testing with the `csh` shell, the following should work in `csh`.

```
sed 's@get_pins {@get_pins -hierarchical {proc_top_*/@g' Input.txt
```

Comment: My output is: get_pins: Event not found

Comment: @starbox What version of sed and which platform?

Comment: @starbox: Sounds like you're using `[t]csh`, where the command line's so-called history expansion feature is getting in your way - try replacing all `!` chars. with `@` chars., for instance.

Comment: Is `csh` seriously trying to expand characters within *single quotes*?

Comment: @Sigi, based on my tests, yes. This might be one of the reasons why `bash` is more popular these days.

Comment: *Cough.*  That *might* be true.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do the replace:

```
awk '{sub(/get_pins {/,"get_pins -hierarchical {proc_top_*/")}1'
```

Comment: Sometimes, `awk` answers are a refreshing counterpoint to `sed` questions - this is not one of those cases: this is just a slightly more verbose and tricky (`1` to ensure that the input line is printed even if there is no match) version of the `sed` command; the (fixed) `sed` command, it should be noted, is a perfectly adequate solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: @mklement0 I was missing the curly brackets, I would for sure not use the `1` if it was not needed. And this is as good as the `sed`.  OP did mention that hi did try `sed`, not that he need a `sed` only solution.

Comment: Now you've made it more verbose - it would have worked without the curly braces (apparently, when `awk` finds multiple patterns that evaluate to true without an associated action, it still only prints the (potentially modified) line only _once_); to recap my point: solutions using a different tool than the OP asked for _can_ be a refreshing alternative, but yours is not.

Comment: @mklement0 OP does not say that he need more than one replace for each line, if so, change from  `sub` to `gsub`.  I normally uses curly brackets and `1` to print it, instead of just the test. It makes it more robust.  If line starts with `0` it may fail with just the test.  Hi tried with `sed` and could not get it to work.  So I do not see any wrong posting `awk` solution.

Comment: I never meant to talk about _multiple_ replacements _per line_ - sorry if I gave that impression. With an `1` as a separate pattern, it doesn't matter what `sub()` returns (for the record: it returns `1` if a replacement was made, `0` if not). Curly braces aside, the need for the `1` (or its more verbose equivalent `{print}`, IF curly braces are used around `sub()`) highlights the awkwardness: `sed` passes _all_ lines out by default, _whether modified or not_, whereas you have to _do extra work_ - however minimal - to achieve that in `awk`.

Comment: To be absolutely clear: I'm not arguing against an `awk` solution _in principle_, I'm arguing against _this_ `awk` solution: (a) it doesn't help the OP understand his/her problem - which is easily fixed, as the other answers attest and (b) even as an _alternative_ solution I don't see the value in this slightly awkward (accidental pun) emulation of the original `sed` command.